# How to prevent API throttling when invoking AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-step-functions

I am using AWS API to invoke AWS Step Functions. However, there are limits to the number of functions that you can call.

According to the AWS Step Function limits, [some Step Functions API actions are throttled using a token bucket scheme to maintain service bandwidth.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/service-limits.html)

For instance, `StartExecution()` has a bucket size of 100 and a refill rate of 2/second.

So, is there a way to monitor the available slots in the bucket?

I looked at the AWS python API, it's called `boto3`, and there does not seem to be a way to obtain this info. But I am not sure.

What would happen to the excess calls, are they queued? or just discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're rejected with an error.  Since this is a protective control, queueing wouldn't make sense, and just discarding excessive requests wouldn't be a sound design practice.

> **Throttling**
>
> The request was denied due to request throttling.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 400
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/CommonErrors.html

You should be able to simply sleep and retry on error, with an exponential backoff.  In it's simplest form, that means you sleep for 1 second and retry, then 2, then 4, then 8, etc.  Even better, add an addtional random interval to each increment, so sleep 1 + rand(1) then 2 + rand(1) or some variation along those lines.

Comment: Thanks again Michael!